# Incrementally Swap Lines Between Two Regex Patterns in a File

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, python

I'm trying to do some text processing on a file using a bash script. The goal is to take all of the lines starting with "field:" indented under an 'attribute:' label and swap them with the associated line starting with "- attr:" that follows.

So far I think I have regex patterns that should match the labels:

`/ *field:(.*)/g`

`/ *- attr:(.*)/g`

But I haven't had any success with the logic to parse through the desired fields and get them to swap correctly.

**Example Input Text**

```
- metric: 'example.metric.1'
  attributes:
      field: 'example 1'
    - attr: 'example1'
      field: 'example 2'
    - attr: 'example2'
      field: 'example 3'
    - attr: 'example3'
      field: 'example 4'
    - attr: 'example4'
- metric: 'example.metric.2'
  attributes:
      field: 'example 5'
    - attr: 'example5'
      field: 'example 6'
    - attr: 'example6'
      field: 'example 7'
    - attr: 'example7'
- metric: 'example.metric.3'
...
```

**Desired Output**

```
- metric: 'example.metric.1'
  attributes:
    - attr: 'example1'
      field: 'example 1'
    - attr: 'example2'
      field: 'example 2'
    - attr: 'example3'
      field: 'example 3'
    - attr: 'example4'
      field: 'example 4'
- metric: 'example.metric.2'
  attributes:
    - attr: 'example5'
      field: 'example 5'
    - attr: 'example6'
      field: 'example 6'
    - attr: 'example7'
      field: 'example 7'
- metric: 'example.metric.3'
...
```

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Probably better to make the upstream process emit valid yaml rather than trying to fix it downstream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '$1=="field:"{s=ORS $0; next} {print $0 s; s=""}' file
- metric: 'example.metric.1'
  attributes:
    - attr: 'example1'
      field: 'example 1'
    - attr: 'example2'
      field: 'example 2'
    - attr: 'example3'
      field: 'example 3'
    - attr: 'example4'
      field: 'example 4'
- metric: 'example.metric.2'
  attributes:
    - attr: 'example5'
      field: 'example 5'
    - attr: 'example6'
      field: 'example 6'
    - attr: 'example7'
      field: 'example 7'
- metric: 'example.metric.3'
```

if you might not have a space after `field:` on some lines or just have a burning desire to use a regexp for some reason then change `$1=="field:"` to `$1~/^field:/` or `/^[[:space:]]*field:/`, whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^ *field: /{h;n;G};p' data
```

If we match a `field` keyword then:

- save the current line in the `hold space` (`h`)
- get the next line from the file in the `pattern space` (`n`)
- swap the `pattern space` with the `hold space` (`G`) (Equals to line swap)

print each line you encounter: `p`

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{if ($1 == "field:") {a=$0;x=0} 
else if (/- attr:/) {$0 = $0 ORS a; x=1} else {x=1}}x' input
```

In this command, if `field:` is found then current input record(`$0`) is saved to variable `a` and x is set to zero. And if `attr:` is found then `$0` is change
d to old `$0` followed by `ORS`(newline) followed by variable `a`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use POSIX sed constructs to flip the said lines.

```
sed '/attr:/!x;$G' file
```